# CanPlaceOn tag along with display name? (Minecraft)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to know how I can use the CanPLaceOn tag along with a display name for a lever.

I've tried this:

```
/give @p lever 1 0 {{CanPlaceOn:[log]},{display:{Name:Jungle Key}}}
```

This doesn't work and says:

```
Data tag parsing failed: Invalid tag encountered, expected '{' as first char.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Simple! Don't use spaces in the `Name` field or it will not be valid JSON. Change it to `JungleKey` or `Jungle_Key`

Comment: It still didn't work when I did /give @p lever 1 0 {{CanPlaceOn:[log]},{display:{Name:Jungle_Key}}}

Comment: Well according to jsonlint.com its not even valid JSON.

Comment: Then how do I get this to work?

Comment: IDK. Maybe try StackOverflow and ask about valid json. (If it has not been asked) I don't do commands much. And when I use JSON I use [this](https://code.google.com/p/quick-json/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create tools with multiple properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349279/how-do-i-create-tools-with-multiple-properties)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two unnamed compound tags where no compound tags are needed. You should remove these:

[image]

Making the correct command:

```
/give @p lever 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:[log],display:{Name:Jungle Key}}
```

The wiki has [a good page on item NBT structure](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Item_structure).

Comment: Thanks so much! I would never got that without your help! :D

Comment: Both jsonlint and [this](http://json.parser.online.fr/) say it is not valid json.

Comment: @TheCodingMonster Doesn't need to be; it works in Minecraft. Try a validator like [this](http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html) and tick all the boxes to make it lenient.

Answer (score 0):

when you just use /give @p chest 1 0 {{CanPlaceOn:[soul_sand]},{display:{Name:grave chest}}} you can remove 5 braclets and can hold that space like this:
/give @p chest 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:[soul_sand],display:{Name:grave chest}}

Comment: Huh, I forgot about this question. To think it was 2 years ago!