# How do I create tools with multiple properties?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create an item that can break certain blocks, but also has a colored name in 1.13.2

Here's the command I'm using.

```
/give iAugust minecraft:shears{display:{Name:"[{\"text\":\"Arcane Shears\",\"color\":\"aqua\",\"italic\":false,\"bold\":false}]CanDestroy:[minecraft:iron_bars]"}}
```

But it only has a colored name, and it can't break specific blocks.

Answer (score 9):

You can add multiple tags (or properties) when giving yourself an item. If you are familiar with JSON it is very similar to that.

In this example `CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:melon_block"]` and `display:{Name:"Box"}` are tags, you can add multiple tags to an item by separating it with a comma.

Therefore you can spawn the item using the following:

`/give @p jukebox 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:melon_block"],display:{Name:"Box"}}`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the map is in adventure mode, all you need to do is put the `minecraft:iron_bars` in quotation marks (" ") and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the problems with your command:

- The text for your `CanDestroy` tag is inside the `Name` tag string. That's trouble. The `Name` tag only accepts JSON text, and you are trying to include other NBT, which messes up the JSON text.
- You need to put `iron_bars` in `"`s.

Here is your updated command:

```
/give iAugust minecraft:shears{display:{Name:"[{\"text\":\"Arcane Shears\",\"color\":\"aqua\",\"italic\":false,\"bold\":false}]"}, CanDestroy:["iron_bars"]}
```

In Minecraft 1.15 and above, you can simplify the whole process by putting the `Name` tag in single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`.

```
/give iAugust minecraft:shears{display:{Name:'[{"text":"Arcane Shears","color":"aqua","italic":false,"bold":false}]'}, CanDestroy:["iron_bars"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to MCStacker for the mining of a certain type of block but just do `/give @p diamond_sword{display:{Name'{"text":"UltraBlade", "color":"light_blue"}` for the colors.

Answer (score -3):

Here's a useful tip when writing coloured writing in Minecraft, use "§"
followed by a number.

For example: `§1 §2 §3 §4 §5 §6 §7 §8 §9 §0`

Comment: That doesn't even work in Java Edition.