# Canplaceon and Named in villager trade

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I can't seem to have a villager trade a named item with `CanPlaceOn` tag.

I read somewhere that this is how it should be formatted, but it is still not working.

Here is a simpler version of the command I'm using: (this one works, but it doesn't have the custom name tag.

```
/summon villager ~ ~1.5 ~ {VillagerData:{profession:nitwit,level:99,type:plains},CustomName:"\"Floor Keys\"",Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:flint,Count:1},sell:{id:end_portal_frame,Count:1,tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:obsidian"]}},maxUses:12}]}}
```

The only difference is more trades of other materials, but I can copy and paste since the output should be the same.

I've tried a ton of different things: Quotes, no quotes, but the `CanPlaceOn` tag doesn't seem to be compatible with the named item?

Comment: From the description of [tag:minecraft-commands]: If you want to ask for help about a command or function that does not work as you expected, please make sure to provide a "[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"

Comment: Like I said, I already tried many different combinations. Quotes, no quotes etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create tools with multiple properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349279/how-do-i-create-tools-with-multiple-properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
tag:{CanPlaceOn:[end_portal_frame]},{display:{Name:"\"Floor Key\""}}
```

This isn’t valid NBT. To put multiple keys in `tag` (or any compound NBT tag), do this:

```
tag:{CanPlaceOn:[end_portal_frame],display:{Name:"\"Floor Key\""}}
```