# How can I put a display name on a custom enchanted item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to put together these two commands:

```
/give @p minecraft:stick{Enchantments:[{id:knockback,lvl:5}]} 1
```

and

```
{display:{Name:'{"text":"Knockback Stick"}'}}
```

Im using Minecraft Java (1.15.2).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create tools with multiple properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349279/how-do-i-create-tools-with-multiple-properties)

Answer (score 0):

```
/give @p minecraft:stick{display:{Name:'{"text":"Knockback Stick"}'},Enchantments:[{id:knockback,lvl:5}]} 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's minecraft 1.15.2 you can do

```
/give @p minecraft:stick{Enchantments:[{id:knockback,lvl:5}],display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Knockback Stick\"}"}}
```

And if you want it to have white text and not be italic, do

```
/give @p minecraft:stick{Enchantments:[{id:knockback,lvl:5}],display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Knockback Stick\",\"color\":\"white\",\"italic\":false}"}}
```