# How do I give myself a pickaxe with multiple abilities?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to make a map where it give you a golden pickaxe with the durability all the way down to just one hit, and at the same time only able to break glass. I already know how to do these two separate commands, but is it possible to put them in the same tool in 1.14?

Comment: Hey there! What have you tried to do already? Please tell us in your answer so we don't potentially give you a command you tried!

Comment: Ooh I tried experimenting on it and I found out the answer. Sorry that I posted a useless question I hope I didn't waste your time in any way and I don't know how to delete this question.

Comment: It's alright! Just post the answer yourself and ill upvote it! I'm happy you found the way, it's alright to!

Comment: If anyone is wondering, the answer I used is /give @p minecraft:golden_pickaxe{CanDestroy:['glass'],Damage:31}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create tools with multiple properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349279/how-do-i-create-tools-with-multiple-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As FlabbyTabby said in the comments, they found the way to do it. Here is what they did:
`/give @p minecraft:golden_pickaxe{CanDestroy:['glass'],Damage:31}`