# How do you set durability AND add a enchant onto a item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I wanted to make an overpowered one-time hit sword that deals knockback and blinds the player who was attacked.
The command for adding enchants is :

```
/give @p diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:STUFF",lvl:SOMETHING},{id:"minecraft:STUFF",lvl:SOMETHING}]}
```

Is it possible to combine the durability command with the enchant command?

Comment: What is the durability command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create tools with multiple properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349279/how-do-i-create-tools-with-multiple-properties)

Comment: Please do 1 question per post

Answer (score 1):

To add damage to an item in a give command, you use the `Damage` nbt tag before enchantments. Use a number that represents the number of durability *lost* from the max. Example:

```
/give @p diamond_sword{Damage:10,Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:STUFF",lvl:SOMETHING},{id:"minecraft:STUFF",lvl:SOMETHING}]}
```

Comment: Not according to MCstacker, at least not to set it.

Comment: Hmm, why does MCstacker use a decimal and tell you to use a decimal to set it?

Comment: In the Give commands durability field info, it states that you need it to be between 0 and 1

Comment: Oh. It appears you are correct, sorry

Comment: Could you do it, given you seem to understand it better?

Comment: Sure, just needed permission from you before I change critical info in posts. It should be done now, feel free to edit it further if you wish.