# if i want to make an item with colored names, unbreakable and enchants higher than maximum 1.16.5

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know that the command for colored items is like this:

```
/give @s diamond_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"fang\",\"color\":\"black\"}"}}
```

and for unbreakable enchanted tools, it is this (from what I remember):

```
/give @s emerald{Unbreakable:1,Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:1000},{id:knockback,lvl:1000}]}
```

Is there a way I can combine the two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create tools with multiple properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349279/how-do-i-create-tools-with-multiple-properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these are JSON objects and you simply need to create a bigger JSON object that contains elements from both of these.

```
/give @s diamond_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"fang\",\"color\":\"black\"}"},Unbreakable:1,Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:1000},{id:knockback,lvl:1000}]}
```