# How do i make an item, that can break certain block, and is named with command blocks in minecraft 1.16?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am doing an prison escape map and i want to make an crowbar to destroy only iron trapdoors and is named crowbar. How???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create tools with multiple properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349279/how-do-i-create-tools-with-multiple-properties)

Answer (score 0):

The "CanDestroy" tag allows an item to break certain blocks in adventure, and using the "Name" tag in "display" lets you name the item.

```
/give @s minecraft:iron_pickaxe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:iron_trapdoor"],display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"crowbar\"}"}}
```