# How to summon mob with a different name and custom attributes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to summon a vindicator named "New_Moon_Warrior" that will have a high follow range. I know the command for both but don't know how to combine them into one command. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create tools with multiple properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349279/how-do-i-create-tools-with-multiple-properties)

Comment: @pppery Although the post may apply, this post refers to armor and the post you referred to was referring to tools.

Comment: The command syntax is the same either way. I never understand this desire to split every separate corner case into its own question rather than pointing people to the correct building blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/summon vindicator ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:'{"text":"New Moon Warrior"}',Attributes:[{Name:generic.follow_range,Base:1000}]}
```

This command should do it.

To add something like a sword, you would do:

```
/summon vindicator ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:'{"text":"New Moon Warrior"}',HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:iron_sword",Count:1b},{}],Attributes:[{Name:generic.follow_range,Base:1000}]}
```

I made the command with MCStacker: https://mcstacker.net/

Comment: For some reason when they are summoned with this command they dont have a weapon, I tried to give them a weapon with /item but it just doesn't work

Comment: To add items you can do it in the /summon command. It would be: 
/summon vindicator ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:'{"text":"New Moon Warrior"}',HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:iron_sword",Count:1b},{}],Attributes:[{Name:generic.follow_range,Base:1000}]}